# DB2 alter a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am new to DB2 and am stuck in altering a stored procedure.

I am on DB2 9.1 version, AIX.

I wrote following SQL in Toad (free version):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE THE_USER.BONUS_MAIN ( )
  REPLACE VERSION V1 ( )

  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
BEGIN
 ...
END
```

I got error message immediately:

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ALTER PROCEDURE THE_USER.BONUS_MAIN" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "".

Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement, you'll need to drop and recreate the procedure.  Additionally, you're on such an old version (DB2 9.1 went out of support in April, 2012), you don't even have an option to use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE...`.

Comment: I see - no wonder I tried 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE..' and it did not work either.